# url changes but view not changes even if using onSameUrlNavigation

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

this is my route configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        component: ThemeComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
        children: [
            {
                path: "",
                component: DefaultComponent,
                children: [

                    {
                    path:"alert-detail/:alertId/:dataCenterLocationId/:deviceId/:parameterId/:methodType/:time/ALERT",
                    component:DashboardComponent,
                    data: { page: 'alert-detail', alertType: 'ALERT' },
                },
                {
                    path:"alert-detail/:alertId/:dataCenterLocationId/:deviceId/:parameterId/:methodType/:time/EVENT",
                    component:DashboardComponent,
                    data: { page: 'alert-detail', alertType: 'EVENT' },
                }
                ]
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: AuthComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'logout',
        component: LogoutComponent
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'index',
        redirectTo: 'dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "404",
        pathMatch: "full"
    }
];

imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes , {onSameUrlNavigation:'reload'})]
```

url changes when trying to navigate between 2 events or 2 alerts but view not changes even if i'm using `onSameUrlNavigation:'reload'` and if i refresh it new view triggers.

how can i solve this problem?

Comment: can you create a minimal working example on stackblitz?

Comment: also see this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21115

Comment: @alt255 i used runGuardsAndResolvers but no change.

Comment: @alt255 i updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across the same problem when trying to refresh a page when clicking on its associated button on the navbar.

Angular doesn't reload the component when set on multiple URLs even though the URLs are different.

So I created my own workaround with this class:

```
/**
 * Abstract class that allows derived components to get refreshed automatically on route change.
 * The actual use case is : a page gets refreshed by navigating on the same URL and we want the rendered components to refresh
 */
export abstract class AutoRefreshingComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public routerEventsSubscription: Subscription;
  protected router: Router;

  constructor() { 
    this.router = AppInjector.get(Router);
  }

  /**
   * Initialization behavior. Note that derived classes must not implement OnInit.
   * Use initialize() on derived classes instead.
   */
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initialize();
    this.routerEventsSubscription = this.router.events.filter(x => x instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(res => {
      this.initialize();
    });
  }

  /**
   * Destruction behavior. Note that derived classes must not implement OnDestroy.
   * Use destroy() on derived classes instead.
   */
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.routerEventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.destroy();
  }

  /**
   * Function that allows derived components to define an initialization behavior
   */
  abstract initialize(): void;

  /**
   * Function that allows derived components to define a destruction behavior
   */
  abstract destroy(): void;

}
```

AppInjector refers to this:

```
import {Injector} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * Allows for retrieving singletons using `AppInjector.get(MyService)` (whereas
 * `ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(MyService)` would create a new instance
 * of the service).
 */
export let AppInjector: Injector;

/**
 * Helper to access the exported {@link AppInjector}, needed as ES6 modules export
 * immutable bindings; see http://2ality.com/2015/07/es6-module-exports.html
 */
export function setAppInjector(injector: Injector) {
    if (AppInjector) {
        // Should not happen
        console.error('Programming error: AppInjector was already set');
    }
    else {
        AppInjector = injector;
    }
}
```

And in your AppModule:

```
import { setAppInjector } from './app.injector';

// ...

export class AppModule {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    setAppInjector(injector);
  }
}
```

Then make all of your needed component extend `AutoRefreshingComponent`.

This may be overkill for what you want to achieve, but it will be useful every time you want to refresh a component on same URL navigation.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: i implemented your solution, in my other routing changes the init and destroy calls but when i change above just the inti calls and no changes in view, i mean the destroy is not called.

Comment: it didn't solve my problem because of my different component structure but helped me to find reason of my problem, thank you.